# django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf: TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doc_type'

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I am creating an django API with Elastic search, using below libraries:

- django-rest-framework
- django-elasticsearch-dsl
- django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf

When api is called, django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf library throws error:

> search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doc_type'

Here is my code:

serializers.py

```
class TestSerializer(DocumentSerializer):
    class Meta(object):
        document = TestDocument
        fields = ("id", "name")
```

api.py

```
class TestDocumentViewSet(DocumentViewSet):
 document = TestDocument
 serializer_class = TestSerializer
 lookup_field = 'id'
 filter_backends = [
    CompoundSearchFilterBackend,
 ]
 multi_match_search_fields  = ('id', 'name')
 filter_fields = {
     'id': 'id',
     'name': 'name',
 }
 ordering_fields = {
     'id': 'id',
     'name': 'name',
 }
 ordering = ('id', 'name')
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

Comment: https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/2204

Answer (score 2):

Yesterday I faced the same problem You need to check the elasticsearch version or You can directly download the version by this command - sudo pip install elasticsearch==version(e.g 6.3.1) 
You can check elastic version by this command - pip freeze

Answer (score 1):

check elasticsearch version. hopefully using compatible versions should solve this problem.

Comment: Can you be more precise? What lead let you think that is a version issue?

Comment: @freezed because I have faced it yesterday.
django-elasticsearch-dsl
requires: Elasticsearch >= 6.0 < 7.0.
but I have installed 7.1.
So, I have got the error.
downgrading the version solved the problem